# Making specific part of node rotate, however appear to be pointing 90 degrees

Tags: game-development, godot, gdscript

Say I have a basic scene tree, like the one below.

```
Control
    Player: Area2d
        Sprite
    Projectile: Area2d
        Sprite
```

The `Projectile` node is a small bullet shaped `area2d` that is set to spin around the player on contact. I have successfully done this by changing the centre offset and centring it on the player, then simply rotating it. This does what I want.
However, whilst it rotates, the bullet shaped projectile visually turns. I don't want this. I want it to always appear to be pointing 90 degrees.

The main problem with my situation is the method on rotating the projectile around the player. Since the centre of the rotation, and the projectile are, in Godot's mind, one Entity, and finding a solution which simply changes what the node's rotation visually is would not work, as then the projectile would not spin around the player at all.

Comment: Depeneding on the approach you are using to rotate, it might be easier to either add another node as an intermediary so it does an opposite rotation, or to do it form code so you only rotate the position.

Comment: @Theraot I'll try forming code to rotate only the position. I imagine simulating the direction changing and putting it into a variable, then moving it around the player with `sin` and `cos`.

Comment: You should be able to do it with `Vector2`, so you don't have to deal with the trigonometrics.